# Dump de todos os bancos para um usuário especifico

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Tenho o usuário plant652 que tem 54 bancos de dados e preciso fazer o backup de todos eles. Como fazer todos de uma única vez no CentOS 6 com cPanel?

Answer (score 2):

Notei que você usou a tag do `mysqldump`. Já que você não informou o sistema operacional que está usando, vou assumir que seja Linux - *que é o mais comum* - caso não seja, você pode usar o conteúdo dessa resposta para adaptar ao seu ambiente. Você vai precisar logar com um usuário e senha pela ferramenta do `mysqldump` se quiser fazer qualquer operação.

Não é ideal executar nenhum script que um estranho na internet escreveu como `root`. :-)
Portanto não vou aconselhar que faça isso. Mas se tiver vários bancos pra ser feito backup e isso estiver devidamente separado em seus respectivos usuários, usar as credenciais de `root` vai te permitir executar o script uma única vez para todos os bancos. Como mencionou que os 54 bancos pertencem ao usuário `plant652`, recomendo que execute como tal. Lembrando, é claro, que para isso você vai precisar da senha.

Não sei de nenhum comando mágico para fazer backup de todos os schemas do MySQL "por padrão".

Por exemplo, criei este script pra resolver o seu (e o meu) problema:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Input the desired MySQL user for backup: " USER
export USER=${USER}

if [ -z "${USER}" ];
then
exit
fi

read -p "Input specified user password: " PASSWORD
export PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}

if [ -z "${PASSWORD}" ];
then
exit
fi

export MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR="/backups/mysql"
mkdir -p ${MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR}/`date +%Y/%m/%d`

#rm "$MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR/*gz" > /dev/null 2>&1

databases=`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P3306 -u $USER -p$PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`

for db in $databases; do
    if [[ "$db" != "information_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != "performance_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != "mysql" ]] && [[ "$db" != _* ]] ; then
        echo "Dumping database: $db"
        mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -P3306 -u $USER -p$PASSWORD --databases $db > ${MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR}/`date +%Y/%m/%d`/$db-`date +%Y-%m-%d`.sql
        gzip ${MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR}/`date +%Y/%m/%d`/$db-`date +%Y-%m-%d`.sql
        tar -cvf ${MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR}/`date +%Y`.tar ${MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR}/`date +%Y`
    fi
done

unset PASSWORD;
unset USER;
```

Agora, explico. Para que o usuário e senha não fiquem armazenados no histórico do shell (e não precisar usar hacks como colocar espaço na frente do comando, que não é garantia de nada ou outras técnicas fora de padrão ou mesmo ficar contando com a memória em apagar o `bash_history`) fiz com o que toda vez que o script fosse executado, ele solicita o usuário e a senha a serem usados (no caso opto pelo `root` que vai enxergar todos os *schemas*) e define o local onde os backups serão salvos, neste caso `/backups/mysql`.

Ele cria as pastas e organiza o backup por YYYY-MM-DD, compacta com a ferramenta **gunzip** e depois cria os archives maiores (que no meu caso é importante) separados por ano pra poder fazer um download simples do ano todo. Ele sobrescreve os arquivos, não otimiza o uso de espaço e comete alguns outros possíveis pecados que pra mim não são relevantes.

No final do script você pode ver que ele descarta os valores das varíaveis que armazenavam o usuário e senha, em uma tentativa de manter isso o mais seguro possível dentro do escopo simples do script.

Se você não quiser digitar isso todas as vezes, provavelmente sua única solução é armazenar em plain text dentro do script e guardar isso no disco. Mas já podemos todos imaginar que essa idéia não é muito legal...

**DISCLAIMER: USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**.

Vale ressaltar a parte mais importante disso tudo:

```
databases=`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P63306 -u $USER -p$PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`

for db in $databases; do
    if [[ "$db" != "information_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != "performance_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != "mysql" ]] && [[ "$db" != _* ]] ; then
        echo "Dumping database: $db"
        mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -P3306 -u $USER -p$PASSWORD --databases $db > ${MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR}/`date +%Y/%m/%d`/$db-`date +%Y-%m-%d`.sql
        gzip ${MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR}/`date +%Y/%m/%d`/$db-`date +%Y-%m-%d`.sql
        tar -cvf ${MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR}/`date +%Y`.tar ${MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR}/`date +%Y`
    fi
done
```

Aqui ele pega o nome de todos os *schemas* (que é claro, têm sua visibilidade afetada pelo usuário cujas credenciais estão sendo usadas pela ferramenta), depois faz um loop e exclui os *possíveis schemas que você não quer incluir no backup*, mais notavelmente os *schemas* protegidos ou padrões do MySQL. A partir dessa lista final ele então faz um `mysqldump` para cada *schema* e salva/compacta conforme explicado anteriormente.

**Importante lembrar:** O usuário `root` ao que me refiro nessa resposta em nenhum momento é o `root` do **sistema operacional**, e sim o do **banco de dados**. Achei importante ressaltar isso para os visitantes da internet que podem passar por aqui no futuro.